# Can I call a stored procedure in Entity Framework 4.x with no input parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have not seen any references to calling stored procedures with EF (currently using 4.3) without passing any parameters in.  Is this considered a bad practice, not supported or something else as I'm not finding the answer any where, The DBA has stored procedures of which many do not have input parameters.

An example anyone.

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that you cannot pass in a null value.  Take a look at ObjectParameter, it has an overload.  Value and Type.

```
 public ObjectParameter(string name, object value);
```

and

```
 public ObjectParameter(string name, Type type);
```

You will need to play with DBNull.Value, and typeof(whatever) etc...
I usually create an input parameter in my stored procedure as a work around as I don't have the time to figure it out with null.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this same issue. If you pass in Null in place of your ObjectParameters it will throw an exception saying that you must have one.

If you pass in DBNull it says that you have specified a parameter on a Sproc that doesn't except parameters and throws an exception.

The only work around for this I have been able to come up with is to modify the sproc to accept a dummy parameter you do nothing with, to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: That is what I decided to do for now unless someone comes up with a good example to show as I'm not seeing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you work database-first, entity framework will show stored procedures, including the ones without input parameters, in the database when you create/update your model. You can include the sprocs in your model and add function imports in the model browser. The context executes the function by calling the non-generic [ExecuteFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986915) method. (It says that it "discards any results returned from the function", but that is not true, see below).

Whether this is bad practice? Not necessarily. I can imagine all kinds of tasks that a user may want to trigger in an application, e.g. some background process that executes a complex calculation or a performance-sensitive process.

Maybe more important than input parameters is that the sproc at least *returns* something so the application can inform the user of if/when/how the sproc finished. Currently, when adding a function import, the only option is to return a collection, not a single scalar value. This means that a `RETURN` statement in the sproc will be ignored by EF. It should at least return values in a `SELECT` statement for EF to be able to collect the output.

Comment: Are you able to call a stored proc without passing in parameters?

Comment: Sure, just something like DoTask() in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can pass no parameters by calling just the name of the stored procedure and leaving out the parameters:

```
context.ExecuteFunction<TestSPROCResult>("TestSPROC");
```

Comment: I will have to check that one.  Thanks Matt